# Disable href with jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having difficulties in disabling href links through jquery. I am using this method I modified. Can some please advise or help me in figuring this out?
Thank you.

**jquery/js**

```
<script>
 $('.next-tab').click(function() {
     $('.st_tab_active').attr('disabled','disabled');
     var tab=  $('.st_tab_active').parent().next().children('a');
     tab.removeAttr('disabled');
     tab.trigger('click');
     return false;
      });
</script>
```

**html**

```
<ul class="st_tabs">
    <li><a href="#st_content_1" class="st_tab" disabled="disabled">Horizontal Tab #1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#st_content_2" class="st_tab" disabled="disabled">Horizontal Tab #2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#st_content_3" class="st_tab" disabled="disabled">Horizontal Tab #3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#st_content_4" class="st_tab" disabled="disabled">Horizontal Tab #4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#st_content_5" class="st_tab" disabled="disabled">Horizontal Tab #5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have no }); at the end of the click function. Was this a mistake in copying or a mistake in the original code? If the latter I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Also see ahrens answer below - I believe this is needed in some browsers.

Comment: also, I believe the attribute 'disabled' is only defined for input fields FYI, some browsers may display other elements with the attribute like 'greyed out' but this is probably not cross-browser

Comment: @Rodolfo yes you are right, chack my answer for the thread on the discussion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `preventDefault();` to disable the default behaviour of links (which is, to navigate to the given `href`).

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

All the answers looks like probable solutions

Here is a discusiion on use of disabled property on anchor tags

[Should the HTML Anchor Tag Honor the Disabled Attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000927/should-the-html-anchor-tag-honor-the-disabled-attribute)

Better, dont use disabled attribute, its kind of illegal ;)

Now you have

```
event.preventDefault();
```

or

```
return false;
```

Here is a discussion on the use of both,

[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

for your case it looks like return false is good as you dont want bubbling as well.

A solution to your exact problem cannot be said as you havent explained the sitation well,

Looks like you are trying to switch tabs with certain enable/disable tabs when some "next tab" is clicked.
If you can explain that also, we will be happy to help

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods you could use, either prevent the default action or a simple return false.

```
$('a').click(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault(); 

    // Rest of the code

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

as ahren previously stated that is the way to go, however in order to not disable every href on your site use: 
    `$('a.st_tab').click(function(e){`
        `e.preventDefault();`
    `});`

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'a' tag, the simplest way I found using JavaScript was to:

1. Add a condition to href (to actually inactivate the link) using an arrow function returning 'false'; and
2. Add the same condition to 'style' (to remove the 'a' tag standard formatting);

Full code below:

```
<a href={(my_condition)? "my_url_here" : () => {return false}} 
   style={(my_condition)? {cursor: "pointer"} : {cursor: "auto", color: "#000"}}
>
```