# Why doesn't jQuery Prop allow an Anchor tag to be set disabled?

Tags: jquery

I thought that .attr and .prop worked interchangeably, but when I tried it with the latest jQuery it doesn't work on Anchors.  I maybe reading the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) wrong, but I just want to make sure I'm not missing something.

```
<a href="#" id="attr">attr</a> 

<a href="#" id="prop">prop</a>


$(function () {
    $("#attr").attr("disabled", true);    // Expected
    $("#prop").prop("disabled", true);    // Not the same
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9JP8/1/)

Comment: Have you gone through [Should the HTML Anchor Tag Honor the Disabled Attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000927/should-the-html-anchor-tag-honor-the-disabled-attribute)

Comment: I can honestly say I wasn't aware that `disabled` was a valid attribute or property for an `<a>` element.

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm not sure if that is sarcasm or not, but why should DOM manipulation check if that be a valid tag/attribute or what not?

Comment: If `prop` and `attr` worked interchangeably, then we wouldn't need both.  Really, they're two different things.

Comment: No, it was a sincere comment. And I have no idea (though I'm half tempted to mark the question as a duplicate of that linked-to by Satpal, above).

Comment: @xivo, assume DOM manipulation does not check validity and that the attribute or property is set as demanded.  Then how's a browser supposed to interpret invalid HTML markup?  Hopefully not at all.

Comment: @DavidThomas According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) it is not valid...

Comment: Looks like I may have misread something.  Satpal's comment wasn't exactly what I was looking for.  I read that before added this question to get clarity on ATTR vs PROP because I read somewhere they were interchangeable.  However, this is not the case and they are two different and similar functions.  I'll close this question because it doesn't seem very clear what I was asking.