# How to determine if <a> is disabled

Tags: html, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

Protractor has the nifty `isEnabled()` function for elements. Though it works great for `<button>`, it isn't doing the trick for `<a>` elements.

I can easily check the `disabled` or `ng-disabled` attribute, but is there a cleaner way?

Comment: The anchor element doesn't (technically) have a "disabled" attribute, so you can't really count on being able to disable it that way (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element). Some browsers will apply the attribute if it's there, but it's not something you should rely on. This question has some decent workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000927/should-the-html-anchor-tag-honor-the-disabled-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the attribute directly like this:

```
expect(myelement.getAttribute('disabled')).toBeTruthy();
```

I use this in my Protractor testing daily without issue.

Comment: This works, even though `getAttibute(...)` will return `null` if the attribute doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, it will return null if the attribute does not exist. This is why you check with .toBeTruthy(). null always evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0):

Even though MBielski's answer would work, a bit cleaner than using `getAttribute()`, would be to use [`isEnabled()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isEnabled):

```
expect(myelement.isEnabled()).toBe(false);
```

Comment: But `isEnabled()` doesn't work for `<a>` elements, unless you know of a mysterious trick

Comment: @MitchellHentges yup, but according to the [a tag HTML5 spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) there is no `disabled` attribute on the `a` tag. See also: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/577. In this github issue, you can see that there are several mentions of using `getAttribute()` directly as a workaround. So, you should probably accept the MBielski's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (dcoument.getElementById("a").disabled) {
    //disabled
} else {
    //active
}
```

Comment: I'm attempting to do this via the [protractor](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) api. I'd need to wrap your solution in a `browser.executeScript(...)` call, which wouldn't be optimal

Comment: I've never heared of `Protactor`, sorry :(

Answer (score -1):

You simple can you use jQuery to determine whenever the attribute is enabled or disabled on a link

$(function() {
    $('input[type="button"]').on('click',function(){

```
    if($('a').prop('disabled')){ // checks whenever the element has the given atribute
    alert('it is enabled');
    } else {

    alert('it is not enabled');
    }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ukLsxna2/1/