# How to disable anchor tags on http call success

Tags: javascript, angularjs, anchor

Can anyone help me with how to disable anchor tag on http call success and enable it on error and vice versa

This is my Html page

```
<a href="#" id="register_pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
    <div class="plus">
        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-plus"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="register">
        <h4>Create</h4>
        <p>New Account</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

This is my controller

```
$scope.MqUser=[];
$scope.getMqUser = function() {
    usSpinnerService.spin('spinner-1');
    MQDetailsService.getUserDetails().success(function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        usSpinnerService.stop('spinner-1');
        $scope.createQ = false;
        $scope.MqUser = data;
        console.log("Success in getting the user list");
        console.log($scope.MqUser);
        //I want the anchor tag to get disabled here using angular directive.
    }).error(function(data,status){
        //I want the anchor tag to get enabled here using angular directive.
        $scope.createQ = true;
        console.log(data);
        if(status == 0){
            $scope.networkError();
        }
        else{
            $scope.fetchuserFail(data.message);
        }
        usSpinnerService.stop('spinner-1');
        console.log("Failed to load the user list "+status);
    })
}
$scope.getMqUser();
```

Answer (score 7):

**A pure AngularJS solution**

In your `success` callback

```
.success(function(data){

    $scope.disableAnchor = true;

})
```

In your `error` callback

```
.error(function(data){

    $scope.disableAnchor = false;

})
```

Your anchor tag

```
<a ng-click='clickAnchor($event)' href="#your_href"> <a/>
```

Then in your controller

```
$scope.clickAnchor = function($event){

   if ($scope.disableAnchor)
         $event.preventDefault()

}
```

**A non pure AngularJS solution**

In your `success` callback

```
.success(function(data){

   $("#your_anchor").on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      return false
    })

})
```

in your `error` callback

```
.error(function(data){

   $("#your_anchor").on('click',function(e){
    })

})
```

I recommend using **Pure Angularjs solution**.

Comment: While this works it is not a pure AngularJS solution. Do you know one that won't use JQuery?

Comment: nice! thanks for the update. Honestly earned upvote :)

Comment: $scope.disableAnchor = true  It doesn't work for anchor tags it only works for button

Comment: @sanmoypaul Im not applying disable tag to anchor element, it is just a scope variable, read the code.

Comment: @sanmoypaul It's just a variable name, you can change it, I'm not using ng-disabled tag.

Comment: instead of using the same code in `success` and `error`, you'd better use `finally`

Comment: @sanmoypaul you can check as correct answer by clicking over the check mark.

Answer (score 4):

you can unbind the click handler in success call back using `jQuery`

```
 .success(function(data){

 $("#register_pointer").unbind( "click" ) // unbind the click
 $("#register_pointer").css( 'pointer-events', 'none' ); //this will also prevent all the events like hover,mouse over etc.
});
```

you can get them back whenever you want as given below

```
 $("#register_pointer").bind( "click" );
 $("#register_pointer").css( 'pointer-events', '');
```

Comment: nice solution. But, pointer-events are not supported in IE <=9

Comment: @VinayK yes pointer events are not supported in IE<=9 ,and it will continue allowing events to be triggered in parent components containing the anchor element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use data-href to enable and disable the anchor tag. Please look at the given code, Hope it will helps yours.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <input type=checkbox onclick="enableEdit(this)"/>
        <div onclick="enable()">Enable</div>
        <div onclick="disable()">Disable</div>

        <a id="anc" data-href="call.html" href="#">click here</a>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function enable() {
                $('#anc').attr("href", $('#anc').data("href"));
            }

            function disable() {
                $('#anc').attr("href", "#");
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: yup by using jQuery I have done....But I need to do this using angular directive.On Ajax Success call the anchor tag will be disabled and on error it should get enabled

Comment: can you provide me the sample code for the your working code.

Answer (score 1):

My humble opinion (which disagrees with the spec - see [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000927/should-the-html-anchor-tag-honor-the-disabled-attribute)) is that the **ng-disabled** directive was created for this exact purpose. Since the disabled attribute has no effect on anchor elements, it's my job to fix it:

```
a[disabled] {
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

[Example here](http://jsbin.com/decalolame/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Note that while pointer-events are not supported on IE<11, it still works because IE also incorrectly acknowledges the disabled attribute on anchors. Other browser support is [pretty good](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).