# cursor: not-allowed; not working in Angular Fullstack + Bootstrap + SASS + Angular-Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button setup like so:

```
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="input-group">
              <label class="input-group-addon">Restart On Failiure?</label>
              <div class="btn-group" ng-model="server.shouldRestart" bs-radio-group>
                <label class="btn btn-default btn-disable"
                       ng-disabled="srvrManagement.edittingServer !== server._id || srvrManagement.edittingItem !== 'settings'">
                  <input type="radio" class="btn btn-default" value="true">Yes</label>
                <label class="btn btn-default"
                       ng-disabled="srvrManagement.edittingServer !== server._id || srvrManagement.edittingItem !== 'settings'">
                  <input type="radio" class="btn btn-default btn-disable" value="false">No</label>
              </div><!--btn group-->
            </div><!--input group-->
          </div><!--/.col-sm-6-->
```

and CSS setup like so:

```
.btn-disable[disabled] {
   cursor: not-allowed;
   background-color: #EEEEEE;
 }
```

The buttons are disabled and I can see in Chrome dev tools that the .btn-disable is being applied but the cursor does not change to the not-allowed cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: This issue is deeper than a simple cursor issue. By adding the pointer-events: all !important; your button will no longer be disabled and the users will be able to click it, but without it you will not be able to change the cursor.

This will require a custom onClick handler to achieve desired result of a button that is disable with a custom cursor on hover. This can be accomplish with angular like so:

```
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="input-group">
              <label class="input-group-addon">Restart On Failiure?</label>
              <div class="btn-group" ng-model="shouldRestart"
                   ng-init="shouldRestart=server.btn.restartOnFailure.get()"
                   ng-change="shouldRestart=server.btn.restartOnFailure.get()"
                   bs-radio-group>
                <label class="btn btn-default"
                       ng-style="server.btn.restartOnFailure.style()">
                  <input type="radio" class="btn btn-default"
                         ng-change="shouldRestart=server.btn.restartOnFailure.onClick(shouldRestart)"
                         value="true">Yes</label>
                <label class="btn btn-default"
                       ng-click=""
                       ng-style="server.btn.restartOnFailure.style()">
                  <input type="radio" class="btn btn-default"
                         ng-change="shouldRestart=server.btn.restartOnFailure.onClick(shouldRestart)"
                         value="false">No</label>
              </div><!--btn group-->
            </div><!--input group-->
          </div><!--/.col-sm-6-->
```

And inside the controller

```
    restartOnFailure: {
      get: function() {
        console.log('get');
        return server.shouldRestart;
      },
      onClick(boolean){
        console.log('onClick');
        if (!self.btns.data.isEditting || self.btns.data.edittingServer !== server._id) {
          console.log('not editing');
          return server.shouldRestart;
        }
        console.log('editing');
        return server.shouldRestart = boolean;
      },
      isDisabled(){
        return self.btns.data[srvrId].restartOnFailure.disabled;
      },
      style(){
        if (!self.btns.data.isEditting || self.btns.data.edittingServer != server._id) {
          return {
            "cursor": "not-allowed",
            "pointer-events": "none !important",
            "background-color": "#EEEEEE"
          }
        }
        return {}
      }
    }
```

What I did was to initialize a model for the bs-radio-group directive and let it handle the actual click of the pair of buttons. Then I detected the change with ng-change. When a change occurred and we are not in an edit state then we set the model back to the state it should be in. This achieved the effect of the buttons being disabled with out using the disabled attribute. In effect allowing us to style the buttons as we like.

A JQuery example here: [Should the HTML Anchor Tag Honor the Disabled Attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000927/should-the-html-anchor-tag-honor-the-disabled-attribute)

My original answer below:

Found it: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16088 it is apparently a know issue with bootstrap.

To fix this problem you have to add the pointer-events: all !important; as bootstrap is striping pointer events on disabled items.

```
.btn-disable[disabled] {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: all !important;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `:disabled` is an alternative, but if your button have the class "btn-disabled" it may still be enabled

```
.btn-disable:disabled {
   cursor: not-allowed;
   background-color: #EEEEEE;
 }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6sobq688/)

Comment: No dice, on Chrome or FireFox.