# Anchor tag disable not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, anchor

I have a code for anchor tag. The Disabled attribute works in IE but not in FF.

Below is the code

```
    <a href="javascript:checkSubmit('help');" disabled="true" "tabindex="<%= tabIndex.getNext()%>"  >
                        Help
    </a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should the HTML Anchor Tag Honor the Disabled Attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000927/should-the-html-anchor-tag-honor-the-disabled-attribute)

Answer (score 2):

`disabled` is not a valid attribute on the anchor tag. Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html

So you cannot possibly expect this to work across all browsers. In order to handle this in a cross browser manner you might need to use some combination of javascript and CSS.

Comment: Do you recommend any other way of disabling it which works across all the browsers.

Comment: Yes, I already mentioned them in my answer: a combination of javascript and CSS should do it.